# Proper management of www.domain.com and domain.com

Tags: web-applications, url, web

I seem to have been running this issue a lot recently.  How is this typically handled? What does it impact?  Is it only a cookie-setting thing?

Should one resolve to the other somehow?  Does it always have to be explicitly set?  If so, where? :)

Does it impact how sessions are handled?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Typically a server admin task -> you might want to go over to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) and ask this; That's where sysadmins who know their stuff hang out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more specific if I didn't give you the right answer, But from what I understand is that you want to know what the urls should resolve.

As far as DNS goes, both www.domain.com and domain.com are an A (ip) record to your webserver.

Inside your webserver both www.domain.com and domain.com should refer to the same (root) directory of your site.

So like I have:
DNS server: www.domain.com and domain.com -Resolve To- xxx.xxx.42.53

WEB server: www.domain.com and domain.com -Resolve To- /var/www/domain/

This is how it's managed by most sites